# Calculating weekends within a month

Tags: javascript, date

I want to build a simple function that would receive a particular month to check. In return it would provide the amount of weekend days it counted within that month.

In the code I'm assuming that the current year is the relevant year to simplify the task.

The problem is it's not return the proper answer for weekends in reality when going over a calendar and counting it manually.

```
workDays(4); // submitting the month to check for

function workDays(monthCheck) //Calculate the actual work days: eliminate weekends from month
{
  // init month to check as proper date variable and setting days to 0 for total days
  var month = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), monthCheck+1, 0);
  var daysOff = 0; //init

 for(i = month.getDate(); i>=0; i--) //check for days that = 0 or 6 (Sunday OR Saturday)
  {

     if(new Date(month.getFullYear(), monthCheck, i).getDay() == 0 || new Date(month.getFullYear(), monthCheck, i).getDay() == 6)
      {
        console.log(daysOff++); // weekend day added to weekend days counter
      }
  }
  return console.log("The days off for the month of " + (month.getMonth()) + " are " + daysOff + " days off.");
}
```

Comment: That seems more like a statement, not a question. What exactly is te problem?

Comment: I guess you want that init `var daysOff = 0; //init` BEFORE the for loop, now you reset it on every iteration

Comment: My mistake I pasted here the wrong script. I updated the daysOff out of the loop.

Comment: The problem is it's not return the proper answer for weekends in reality when going over a calendar and counting it manually.

Comment: @EdanBen-Atar did my answer help?

Comment: Seems to me `monthCheck+1` should be `monthCheck` since January is 0 and you're setting the date to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find your logic very confusing. I refactored the code to an (imo) more readable version, and the result seems as expected:

```
nonWorkDays(4);

function nonWorkDays(month)
{
  var current = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), month - 1, 1);
  var daysOff = 0; //init

  // as long as our date is in the requested month
  while (current.getMonth() == month -1) {
    // saturday or sunday?
    if (current.getDay() == 0 || current.getDay() == 6) {
      daysOff++; 
      console.log(daysOff, current); 
    }

    // move to next day
    current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1);
  }
  console.log("The days off for the month of " + month + " are " + daysOff + " days off.");

  return daysOff;
}
```

And a fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/4kmtemfy/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you went wrong but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/z75ku/325/) seems right:

```
var d = new Date();
var getTot = daysInMonth(d.getMonth(),d.getFullYear());
var weekends = new Array();

for(var i=1;i<=getTot;i++){
    var newDate = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),i)
    if(newDate.getDay()==0 || newDate.getDay()==6){
        weekends.push(i)
    }

}
console.log(weekends.length);

function daysInMonth(month,year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with `monthCheck+1`. Since months are zero indexed and you want the month number of the following month, don't subtract 1. You can also simplify the logic somewhat:

```js
function workDays(monthCheck) {
  // Create date for last day of month to check
  var month = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), monthCheck, 0);
  var daysOff = 0;

  // For each day of the month
  for(var i = month.getDate(); i>=0; i--) {
    // Add day off for Saturday and Sunday
    if (!(month.getDay()%6)) {
      daysOff++;
    }
    month.setDate(month.getDate()-1);
  }
  return daysOff;
}

var month = 4;
console.log('Days off for ' + month + ' are ' + workDays(month) + '.');
```